# android shared preference is null

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i am using `shared preference` in android but it return null,
i saw a lot of code example for this and i can't see any error in my code

```
 SharedPreferences sp =this.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    Log.v("sharedpref",""+username+": "+password);
    editor.putString("email", username);
    editor.putString("pass",password);
    editor.apply();
```

and here i am retrieving the data from shared preference (in another activity)

```
SharedPreferences sp =this.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Log.v("shersend",""+sp.getString("email", "Empty")+": "+sp.getString("pass", "Empty"));

            String email = sp.getString("email", "Empty");

            String pass = sp.getString("pass", "Empty");
```

so is there any problem with my code?
and is there a better  to write this?

Comment: Are your "MYPREFERENCES" constants in both activities the same?

Comment: `but it return null` what? `SharedPreferences` is `null` or `username` and `password` is `null`?

Comment: the data in it is null, in my code it print "Empty"

Comment: make sure `Log.v("sharedpref",""+username+": "+password);` this line prints not null values.

Comment: use this.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  see my answer below

Comment: before getting it from `SharedPreferences`..make sure you're storing valid values in `SharedPreferences`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are saving the preference in one Activity say A, And accessing in another activity say B, and context of both activities are different and so preferences values cannot be accessed as mode is private.

try

```
this.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try that way, Change this code block

```
SharedPreferences sp =this.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to this code block

```
SharedPreferences sp= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: Did you try change for MainActivity and your another activity. Cause you need to chane both, I tried that way and ıt works for me. Hope you will solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `getApplicationContext()`

```
SharedPreferences sp =getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    Log.v("sharedpref",""+username+": "+password);
    editor.putString("email", username);
    editor.putString("pass",password);
    editor.commit();
```

Comment: He's using apply, which is actually better than commit.